# Circle of Apollonius modified to inversion form

Tags: circles, inversive-geometry

Let $A$ be any point outside the circle $\omega$, let $A^*$ be its inverse around $\omega$, and $P$ is any variable point on $\omega$. Prove that the ratio $PA$/$PA^*$ is constant, and hence find its value in terms of $P$ , $A^*$, and $A$.

[image]

Upto which I could do, but can't understand the last line of my solution:

[image]

Comment: Please solve this using inversion as this question was there in the chapter of inversion .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because A'  is inverse of A around ω we can write:
OA * OA' = r²   ⇔  OA / r = r / OA'  ⇔  OA / OP = OP / OA'  (1)
Because ∡α has the sides proportional in  △OAP  and  △OPA'
then triangles are similar.
(Two triangles are similar if  the corresponding lengths of two sides
are proportional and the included angles are congruent (SAS).)
We can add to (1) the ratio:
PA / PA' = OA / OP = OP / OA'  (2).
Let k be the common value of those ratios. We'll prove that k is constant.
Indeed, from properties of proportions we have:
If  a/b = c /d   then  we can add the ratio  (a - c) / (b - d) to that
proportion and so we can write:
a/b = c/d = (a - c) / (b - d).
So applying this property to the last proportion in (2) we have:
k =  OA / OP = OP / OA' =  (OA - OP) / (OP - OA').
But OP = OB (where B = ω ∩ OA) and we have:
OA - OP = OA - OB = AB  and  OP - OA' = OB - OA' = A'B
So we have:
k = PA / PA' = AB / A'B = const,   qed.

Observation:
The last proportion says that PB is the angle bisector in △APA'.
The angle bisector theorem is concerned with the relative lengths
of the two segments that a triangle's side is divided into by a line
that bisects the opposite angle. It equates their relative lengths
to the relative lengths of the other two sides of the triangle.